# Concept dead letter exchange not working in my environment

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I try to use the dead letter exchange with annotations in my java code. Maybe is my assumption wrong how it should work. But in my method processMpcMessage I deserialize the message from a Queue into a POJO. If I get a IllegalargumentException I want that the message is put onto a dead letter queue. I configured the deadletter exchange and routing key see my code example.
If I throw "throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(msg, exception);" I expect that the message I consumed earlier is put onto the dead letter queue.
I get how ever the following debug message:

> 2019-02-07 13:35:42,009 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG {} - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Rejecting messages (requeue=false)

Any advise is welcome
Regards
Dirk

```
    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
                                value = @Queue(
                                        value = "${mpc.inbound.receive.queue}",
                                        durable = "true",
                                        arguments = {
                                                @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange", value = "${mpc.inbound.dead.letter}"),
                                                @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-routing-key", value = "${mpc.inbound.receive.error.routing.key}"),
                                                @Argument(name = "defaultRequeueRejected", value = "false")
                                        }),
                                        exchange = @Exchange(value = "${mpc.inbound.exchange}",
                                        type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, durable = "true"),
                                        key = "${mpc.inbound.routing.key}"
                                ))
public void processMPCMessage(final Message message) {
//Here the message is deserialized in to a java object and this is where I want to throw a exception. 
try{
}catch(IllegalArgumgenException ex){
    throw new new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(" a error message", ex);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the queue already exist?

Queues are idempotent; you can't change their properties (arguments) after they are created. Delete it first so it will be recreated.

If that's not it, turn on DEBUG logging to see what's going on.

Comment: The queue does exist. Debug is on and I can see that the applicatioin is connected to the queue. I don't see the dead letter exchange and routing key information in the log. In rabbitmq the arguments are available on the queue

Comment: `Rejecting messages (requeue=false)` well, clearly the message is being rejected and not requeud; so either the routing key is wrong, or there is no queue bound to the DLX with that routing key.

Comment: I configure it all new and now starting to work. I other words my RabbitMQ environment was meshed up. Thanks for the advise

Comment: One more note to this, not solution to the question but a mistake made in the code.
Param @Argument(name = "defaultRequeueRejected", value = "false") is not something that should be set on queue but as a spring boot propertie 

`spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.default-requeue-rejected: false`

and in that case there is no need of throwing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException exception